# Anyway to do this via WP-Config.php? (Wild Card Redirect except wp-admin)

Tags: php, wordpress

The goal is to catch all urls and redirect it to homepage. But will not redirect wp-admin and wp-login.php.

This code works fine and does just that.

in **functions.php** but Is there anyway to do this pure PHP in **wp-config.php**?

```
/** WordPress Wild Card Redirect to Home Page */

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');

function redirect_to_home()
{
    if (!is_home() || is_page() || is_single())
    /** If the page is not home */
    {
        /** Redirect to home url */
        wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/')));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works just fine, why do you want to move it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was just trying to see if it is possible? As much as possible we don't want to add any code in functions.php that is the reason why. Weird management you know ^_^

Comment: Well, `wp-config.php` is not a good place for it. That file gets loaded during the bootup of Wordpress. Since that file contains the database credentials, there won't even be an available database connection when the file get's parsed by PHP. If you can't have it in `functions.php` (which is, imo, where it should be) you can always create a plugin instead.

Comment: I see thanks @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

wp-config its not the place, create your own plugin and start coding there, so you can reuse in all your developments.

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: My nice plugin
 * Author: Your name
 */


/** WordPress Wild Card Redirect to Home Page */

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');

function redirect_to_home()
{
    if (!is_home() || is_page() || is_single())
    /** If the page is not home */
    {
        /** Redirect to home url */
        wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/')));
        exit();
    }
}
```